# ordinal encoding is not for logistic regression

Tags: encoding, logistic-regression, ordinal

Why can't we use ordinal encoding for logistic regression?
They write that it is not suitable for logistic regression, but suitable for decision trees and random forests. In logistic regression, one hot encoding is most often used. Explain, please.